# How can I use streams on this PieChart

Tags: flutter

I recently started learning flutter and I learnt reactive programming in flutter (Learning it actually).
Here's what i want, I have a PieChart that takes a map as an input and draws it. (Suppose the map map = { "Food" : 5, "Transportation" : 2}
What i want to do is to have a button that when i click would increment the food by 1 and then the PieChart would rerender. (eventually the button would allow the user to add their own string and int but for now i hardcode for testing) 
My idea is to have a PieChart wrapped with a StreamBuilder that would watch over a stream and rebuild the PieChart when we add input to that stream.
I just don't know how to implement it properly, i also don't know if i should make the stream take in a map, or some class called deposit that has a string and a double for example.
Here's my boilerplate:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pie_chart/pie_chart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Map<String, double> dataMap = {"Food": 5, "Transportation": 3};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Testing"),
        ),
        body: PieChart(dataMap: dataMap),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            dataMap["Food"] = dataMap["Food"] + 1;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pie_chart/pie_chart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Map<String, double> dataMap = {"Food": 5, "Transportation": 3};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Testing"),
        ),
        body: PieChart(dataMap: dataMap),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() => dataMap["Food"] += 1);

          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

All you need to do is use setState to tell the widget the state has changed.
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

This pattern is inspired by Reactjs. Note: do not put compute heavy operations in `setState` callback

Here is an example of a Stream

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/sensors/example/lib/main.dart

I do not have the Stream function, so I cannot write code.

Comment: Is there a way to use streams instead? Wrapping the piechart with a streambuilder and then upon adding input into that stream the piechart rerenders? that's what i'm trying to accomplish but for some reason it doesn't work (the piechart never rerenders)

Comment: also how can i use setstate? My homepage is stateless or am i missing something? (I'm new to flutter)

Comment: When you use stream, you put it in `initState()` function and add a listener. A sensor app has a good example

Comment: could you please show me or send me a link of where i could see an example?

Comment: @Abbas, i sent you a link to the sensors app. you put it here
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/sensors/example/lib/main.dart#L122

`initState()` is a function which run when the widget is inserted into the tree. You add your start listening callback there

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know about the basics of Streams and how to use it [this](https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/fundamentals-of-dart-streams/) is the post you are looking for you can learn mucho from it.

You can learn that and much more from Thomas Burkhart even a new pattern call RxVMS.